# Cannot purge roundup

Tags: dpkg, aptitude, apport, purge, ureadahead

I was trying to purge `roundup`, and `aptitude` has output the following error lines:

```
update-rc.d: /etc/init.d/roundup exists during rc.d purge (use -f to force)
dpkg: error processing roundup (--purge):
 subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 1
Processing triggers for ureadahead ...
No apport report written because MaxReports has already been reached
                                                                    Errors were encountered while processing:
 roundup
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
A package failed to install.  Trying to recover:
```

`aptitude`'s logs do not help; the following line is written there:

```
IMPORTANT: this log only lists intended actions; actions which fail due to
dpkg problems may not be completed.
```

but the following two lines appeared in `apt/history.log`:

```
Purge: roundup:amd64 (1.4.18-1.1)
Error: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

[`roundup`](http://www.roundup-tracker.org/), by the way, is an issue-tracking system with command-line, web and e-mail interfaces. I don't use it.

---

**System information:** I am using Ubuntu 12.04.4 LTS, output of `uname -srvmpio` is:

```
Linux 3.2.0-61-generic #93-Ubuntu SMP Fri May 2 21:31:50 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

---

As requested, I have tried the following command:

```
sudo dpkg -P --force-all --force-remove-reinstreq roundup
```

and the output was:

```
Removing roundup ...
update-rc.d: /etc/init.d/roundup exists during rc.d purge (use -f to force)
dpkg: error processing roundup (--purge):
 subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 1
Processing triggers for ureadahead ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 roundup
```

It may worth mentioning that this was done both before and after running the command

```
sudo update-rc.d -f roundup remove
```

---

**Update:** update the failing attempts to purge, the state of the package, according to `aptitude`, was `H`, which means *half-installed*. I have tried to reinstall it (was successful) and remove it again, but with no luck - same error has appeared, and the state is back again *half-installed*.

Comment: Try using the -f options as in the error message. If that fails, try `sudo rm /etc/init.d/roundup`. You should probably file a bug report against roundup

Comment: @bodhi.zazen - tried `sudo update-rc.d -f roundup remove`; that removed some startup links, it seems. Later, `sudo dpkg -P roundup` still failed, with the same error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to forcely remove the `roundup` package,

```
sudo dpkg -P --force-remove-reinstreq roundup
```

Or

Try to move the `roundup-dirs` and `roundup` to some other location and then try the above command like,

```
sudo mv /etc/init.d/roundup-dirs ~/
sudo mv /etc/init.d/roundup ~/
sudo dpkg -P --force-all --force-remove-reinstreq roundup
```

Comment: Did you mean `-P` instead of `-p`?

Comment: sorry, capital P.

Comment: Both commands failed, with the same error.

Comment: post the output of `sudo dpkg -P --force-all --force-remove-reinstreq roundup` in your question.

Comment: now try this `sudo mv /etc/init.d/roundup ~/` and then run `sudo dpkg -P --force-all --force-remove-reinstreq roundup`

Comment: Now the same error existed, but with `roundup-dirs` instead of `roundup`. I have moved that file as well and tried again. That did the job - thanks!

Comment: what did you tried?

Comment: did you tried this `sudo dpkg -P --force-all --force-remove-reinstreq roundup-dirs` ?

Comment: No; I have done `sudo mv /etc/init.d/rounfup-dirs ~/` and then `sudo dpkg -P --force-all --force-remove-reinstreq roundup`.

Comment: may i post it as an answer?

Comment: Absolutely, do that! (or perhaps edit that one)

Comment: i think the first command wold be `sudo mv /etc/init.d/roundup-dirs ~/`

Comment: Sorry to bother, but I think that you still need (perhaps) the moving of `/etc/init.d/roundup` as well. I've moved both files.